# In tortoise ORM How do you specify an Duplicate Error in a Integrity Error and retry the save() method

Tags: python, mysql, tortoise-orm

Hi id like to make product code with continuous and unique number. First I tried making a module function code that increases the last number that was used to produce a code. For example if my last product_code was P1, the last number that is saved in my DB will be 1, resulting my next product_code to be P2. Unfortunately due to multiple workers this method has shown to produce duplicate codes if it is ran simultaneously by the uvicorn workers.

I tried to declare the code field `unique=True` and retry on integrity errors as below

I wanted to catch a specific IntegrityError `1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'products ~~~`

```py
class Product(model):
    code = fields.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)`

class GlobalCount(models):
    type = fields.CharField()
    count = fields.IntField()
```

if P1 exists the `GlobalCount`'s `type='product_code'` `count` will be `1`

```py
product = Product(code="")
g_count = await GlobalCount.get(type='product_code')

while True:
    g_count.count += 1
    await g_count.save()
    product.code = f'P{g_count.count}'

    try:
        await product.save()

    except IntegrityError[0]==1062:
        continue

    except Exception:
        raise Error

    break
```

I cant seem to specify it or process it under conditions, I will be most thankful if there is any way to catch this or more over if there is a more proper practice to produce custom distinct continues codes.

Comment: You should do a locking read in the globalcount.get method (select ... for update). This way only one session can read the specific value in the globalcount table. No clue how to this in an orm, though.

Comment: To be honest, unless there is a legal requirement of having consecutive product ids, I would push back on this requirement and use a simple auto incremented id and accept the fact that there may be gaps in the list of ids. This requirement requires your application to somehow serialise the creation of new products, which is likely to cause a performance bottleneck in a highly concurrent application.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow!! My organization  unfortunately needed customized ids for this project for reasons I can't explain in short terms! But locking the db is a great suggestion it worked for me for there is a method that support this in tortoise orm!